# ConnectToConnectionPoint Windows function not return Token for dynamic Textbox to catch Enter or Exit event

Tags: excel, vba, dll, textbox, userform

The initial task is to create a run-time Textbox on a Userform, and catch the Enter and Exit events in a VBA code.

Creating the form and dynamic add of controls working fine, i have stucked at the catching of events, since these are not included in the created object. For the first sight eems a relatively simple work.

After nearly a week searching, and from several posts and documents (from EvR, Rubberduck, JonS et al.)  i can get near to achieve something on which i can continue. The problem is still that while the function returns with **0 error code, no token** is passed back.

The relevant part of the code

TextBoxCreator Class Module

```vb
Private Declare Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi.dll" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef riidEvent As eventguide, ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByVal pdwCookie As Long, Optional ByVal ppcpOut As Long) As Long
Private oTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Private Type eventguide
data1 As Long
data2 As Integer
data3 As Integer
data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Public Property Let SetControlEvents(ByVal TextBox As Control)
Dim conIID As eventguide
With conIID
   .data1 = &H20400
   .data4(0) = &HC0
   .data4(7) = &H46
End With
       Set oTextBox = TextBox
       Dim RetVal As Long
         a = StrPtr("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
         Debug.Print a
         RetVal = IIDFromString(a, testvalue)
        If RetVal = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Connection ID:   ", testvalue
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error:   ", RetVal, Hex(RetVal)
        End If
        
    conreturn = ConnectToConnectionPoint(Me, conIID, True, TextBox, cookie)
    Debug.Print conreturn, Hex(conreturn), cookie
    
End Property
```

This is in UserForm1 code module

```vb
Dim firs As TextBoxCreator
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Set newtextbox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("forms.textbox.1", , True)
Set demobox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("forms.textbox.1", , True)
demobox.Top = 30
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_AddControl(ByVal Control As MSForms.Control)
Set firs = New TextBoxCreator
firs.SetControlEvents() = Control

End Sub
```

Tried function declaration with `Alias "#168"`, same result.

The printout:

```
 29616520 
Connection ID:               132096 
 0            0             
 29616520 
Connection ID:               132096 
 0            0
```

How can i reach to get a valid cookie value to continue?